# Access request in django custom template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

My code in myapp_extras.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('new/userinfo.html')
def address():
    address = request.session['address']
    return {'address':address}
```

in 'settings.py':

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS =(
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    'django.core.context_processors.request'
)
```

but I got an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /items/

Caught an exception while rendering: global name 'request' is not defined

Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 71, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\__init__.py", line 915, in render
    dict = func(*args)
  File "C:\p4\projects\myproject\..\myproject\invoice\templatetags\myapp_extras.py", line 9, in address
    address = request.session['address']
NameError: global name 'request' is not defined
```

I referenced this one
[In Django, is it possible to access the current user session from within a custom tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335231/in-django-is-it-possible-to-access-the-current-user-session-from-within-a-custom).

Comment: Hmmm... The answers to that linked-to question seem wrong...

Comment: if you want to access request check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2567234/1153703

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`request` is not a variable in that scope. You will have to get it from the context first. [Pass `takes_context` to the decorator and add `context` to the tag arguments](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('new/userinfo.html', takes_context=True)
def address(context):
    request = context['request']
    address = request.session['address']
    return {'address':address}
```

Comment: it seems i still got errors
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Caught an exception while rendering: 'request'

Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 71, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\__init__.py", line 936, in render
    dict = func(*args)
  File "c:\...\myapp_extras.py", line 7, in login
    request = context['request']
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'request'

Comment: i noticed in this page http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/

"DJANGO.CORE.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.REQUEST
If TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS contains this processor, every RequestContext will contain a variable request, which is the current HttpRequest. Note that this processor is not enabled by default; you'll have to activate it."

somewhere i need to configure to activate request processor

Comment: Why is this the case with inclusion_tag?

Comment: The MVP separation in Django prevents it from seeing anything about the request itself, so it must be fed to the tag.

Comment: Don't forget to add `django.template.context_processors.request` to `TEMPLATES` in your _settings.py_ otherwise **request** will not be included in **context**

Answer (score 12):

I've tried solution from above (from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams) and it actually didn't work until I've found out that context processors works only with `RequestContext` wrapper class.

So in main view method you should add the following line:

```
from django.template import RequestContext        
return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form, }, 
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Indeed, context_instance = RequestContext(request) is a missing piece. Use it!

Comment: If you are rendering the response to string/html, you can do without RequestContext. `@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
`, and then `def my_tag(context, ...) ... return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form, }, context_instance = context)`.

Answer (score 10):

I've done this way:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def do_test_request(parser,token):
    try:
        tag_name = token.split_contents() # Not really useful
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r error" % token.contents.split()[0])
    return RequestTestNode()

class RequestTestNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self,):
        self.request = template.Variable('request')
    def render(self, context):
        rqst = self.request.resolve(context)
        return "The URL is: %s" % rqst.get_full_path()

register.tag('test_request', do_test_request)
```

There is also a function called `resolve_variable`, but it's deprecated.

Hope it helps!