# Template tag and request object

Tags: django

Each time a request is made to my app, I am using middleware to retrieve and store a 'Page' object which has information relevant that particular page. I am storing a reference to this object in the request object, here is an example:

```
class PageMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request, 'page'):
            request.page = Page.objects.get(slug=<slug>)
        return None
```

It works well enough, but I want to access this object in a template tag. Template tags only have a reference to 'context' thought, meaning I am unable to see my Page object.

I know I can use a custom context processor for this but that means modifying the settings file further and I'd like to try and keep this app as encapsulated as possible. I noticed, for example, that the Debug Toolbar app manages to append data to the template context without modifying the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

In short, I want to access my Page object in a template tag ideally by just using middleware. Any ideas?

Edit: I am using a standard template tag, with the following class:

```
class GetPageContentNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def render(self, context):
        return context['request'].page
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this, you can get access to the request object (and your object) by passing takes_context when registering the template tag

[Access request in django custom template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160261/access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags)

Have a search for "takes_context" on this page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have said in my original post that I am using a standard tag and not a inclusion tag. Calling context['request'] causes a key error.

Comment: it should work on normal template tags too. Inclusion & Simple template tags are just wrappers for normal template tags

Answer (score 1):

Call every `render_to_response` with a [context_instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) parameter, like:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
     return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

EDITED as sugested by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman):

And add [django.core.context_processors.request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) to your [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) settings.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the second part of this - there is already a [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request), although you need to specifically enable it in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class GetPageContentNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def render(self, context):
        request = template.Variable('request').resolve(context) # here's the magic!
        return request.page
```