# How to make the login form available on whole site on Django

Tags: django, authentication

I'm using Django registration to manage the registration and login / logout together with Django's auth system. It's working fine, I have a base template where I have put a 'login' link that takes the user to another page to login. I'd like to replace this link with the actual login form (username / password) so the form appears directly in every page. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should note that if your site is visible over HTTP and your login page is HTTPS (as it should be) then the HTTP --> HTTPS POST will fail due to the CSRF check. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13849 or http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/22058adaf11e3ed6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [inclusion template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) to build a custom tag that looks like:

```
{% login_form %}
```

You might want to pass this tag the `request.get_absolute_uri` so that it can use it in a `?next={{ request.get_absolute_uri }}` parameter to the login view so that the user can be redirected to the current page after login.

This way, you can put the login form anywhere you want in any template without violating the DRY principles.  You can even embed it in your base template using something like:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
  {% login_form %}
{% else %}
  {# display welcome message. #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I almost got it working the way you describe it but I don't understand how I can access the request from within the view of the tag, any hint?

Comment: ok, got it from here [access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160261/access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags)

Comment: But even with access to request I don't get how to pass the request.get_absolute_uri. Could you clarify it please?

Comment: @Bastian: follow the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2160298/313063) in the question you linked to.  Just use the `takes_context` switch, access the request, fetch the URI (still all in Python) and put it in the new context variables dictionary (your template tag function's return value) and access that from your login form template.

Comment: I like your approach, very clean!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of different ways you could do this:

1. Modify your base template and hardcode the form (it is only a few
   fields - don't forget the CSRF token).
2. Use a context processor to make a Django form variable
   available to every template.
3. Create a custom template tag to display
   the form and use it on your base template.

You'll likely want to wrap the logic in the template like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <!-- maybe show a logout link -->
{% else %}
   <!-- display your form using one of the methods above -->
{% endif %}
```

Note: if you are using the [auth template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth), the user variable will be available on all your templates.

Answer (score 1):

I have embedded my login form within the base template, and pass `request.user` along to the templates of my site to display the login form only if the user is not already logged on.

So in my view dict I include `'user': request.user` and my template looks similar to this:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
<form><fieldset><!-- Your login form here --></fieldset></form>
{% else %}
<!-- If you want to display something else if the user is logged in, like -->
<p>Welcome, {{ user }}!</p>
{% endif %}
```