# Login on every page with inclusion tags: example and doubts

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I need a Login form on every page of my project and I'm implementing it with [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). With django documentation and some examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384922/how-to-make-the-login-form-available-on-whole-site-on-django), I've written the following code so far:

- project tree:

  ```
  myProj
  ├── myProj
  │   └── settings.py
  ├── celeryPy2
  │   ├── forms.py
  │   ├── templatetags
  │   │   └── my_tags.py
  │   ├── urls.py
  │   └── views.py
  └── templates
      ├── base.html
      └── celeryPy2
          ├── login.html
          └── start.html
  ```
- urls.py

  ```
  from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

  urlpatterns = patterns('celeryPy2.views',
      url(r'^$',    'start',   name='start'),
      url(r'^accounts/login/$', login,  name='login'),
      url(r'^accounts/logout/$', logout, {'next_page':'/celeryPy2'}, name='logout'),
  )
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  def start(request):
      return render_to_response('celeryPy2/start.html', {},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```
- start.html

  ```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block title %}celeryPy2 start page{% endblock title %}
  {% block content %}
  {% load my_tags %}
  {% login_form %}
  {% endblock content %}
  ```
- base.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>celeryPy2</title></head>
  <body>
      <div id="header">{% block header %}{% endblock %}</div>
      <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
      <footer id="footer">{% block footer %}{% endblock %}</footer>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- my_tags.py

  ```
  from django import template
  register = template.Library()

  from celeryPy2.forms import UserForm

  @register.inclusion_tag('celeryPy2/login.html', takes_context=True)
  def login_form(context):
      form = UserForm
      user = context['user']
      return {'form': form,'user': user}
  ```
- forms.py

  ```
  class UserForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('username','password')
  ```
- login.html

  ```
  {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
      <form  id="idLogInForm" method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}?next=/celeryPy2" class="loginForm">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <button id="idLogInSubmit" name="idLogInSubmit" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
  {% else %}
      <form id="idLogOutForm" method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}">{% csrf_token %}
          <span id="welcomeUserId" class="welcomeUserClass">Welcome, <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong></span>
          <button id="idLogOutSubmit" name="idLogOutSubmit" type="submit">Logout</button>
      </form>
  {% endif %}
  ```

I have the following issues and doubts:

1. Is that a correct way to implement it or I can get security issues?
2. When I insert wrong user credentials I correctly get the error `Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.` and the browser url bar is set to `/celeryPy2/accounts/login/?next=/celeryPy2`. But if I try to re-login, it tries to reach the non existent url `/accounts/profile/`. Why? I have to say that I have no `LOGIN_URL` or `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in my settings.py. **[SOLVED, see below]**
3. Why I get the password input field with clear text and not hidden by masked characters as it should be? **[SOLVED, see below]**
4. Why I get the label `Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters` beside the username input field? **[SOLVED, see below]**

This is the way I found to have a code plug-in to reuse in every page, being more compliant as possible with django built in features. It looks a little tricky to me (a lot of files involved) and probably something is still to be refined, but I found this is the easiest way to get my task accomplished.
Any other **better** ideas are welcome!

Comment: I've resolved points 2, 3 and 4 with code corrections reported below. Only point 1 is still opened...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved points 2, 3 and 4 with the following code modifications:

- urls.py

  ```
  from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

  urlpatterns = patterns('celeryPy2.views',
      url(r'^$',    'start',   name='start'),
      url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name':'celeryPy2/login.html'},  name='login'),
      url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'next_page':'/celeryPy2'}, name='logout'),
  )
  ```
- forms.py

  ```
  from django.forms import CharField
  from django.forms import ModelForm, PasswordInput
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User

  class UserForm(ModelForm):
      username = CharField()
      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('username','password')
          widgets = {'password': PasswordInput()}
  ```
- login.html

  ```
  {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
      <form  id="idLogInForm" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" class="loginForm">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <button id="idLogInSubmit" name="idLogInSubmit" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
  {% else %}
      <form id="idLogOutForm" method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">{% csrf_token %}
          <span id="welcomeUserId" class="welcomeUserClass">Welcome, <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong></span>
          <button id="idLogOutSubmit" name="idLogOutSubmit" type="submit">Logout</button>
      </form>
  {% endif %}
  ```

In the end I've added `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/celeryPy2'` to myProj/settings.py.

Point 1 is still open: is this implementation a good one or could lead up to to security issues?