# Access request in django custom template tags, using the tag decorator

Tags: django, django-templates

There is a question with the same title and problem: [Access request in django custom template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160261/access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags)

The solution proposed, for instance pass `takes_context = True` to the decorator works perfectly well for tag helpers (`simple_tag`, `inclusion_tag` and `assignment_tag`) but not with the low-level `tag` decorator.

```
@register.tag(takes_context=True)
def mytag(parser, token):
   ...
```

raises the exception :

> tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'takes_context'

2 questions :

- is there a reason why the `tag` decorator does accept the `takes_context` argument ?
- how can I access the template context with this decorator (and thus the request object) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the 2 sub-questions:

> Is there a reason why the `tag` decorator does accept the `takes_context` argument ?

It's because, as you said, `tag` is run at a lower level, parser-level of the template. There is no context at that point.

> How can I access the template context with this decorator (and thus the request object) ?

I don't think you can. Again, because it's a parser-level thing. An interesting example is the `block` tag. In order to be able to override `block` tags, it uses the `extend` tag to pass on some info.

I'm struggling with similar situation. The only thing I can think of is making middleware for `process_request` that resets some global/singleton context which I access in tags. However this wont help if a template is rendered outside a request, like in a command.

Answer (score 1):

`@register.tag` takes only two arguments: the name and the compilation function. I think you can try to pass `request` through the [token argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag) in the compilation function.

UPD:
You can also access it in the Node `render` method

```
class TestTagNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return context['request'].user

@register.tag
def test_tag(parser, token):
    return TestTagNode()
```

Comment: Sure passing the request as an argument would work, but I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to...

Comment: Thanks for this update, but still, I need to access the request in the tag function, not in the node. It is weird there is no way to do it, without explicitly passing request as an argument, which I want to avoid.