# Using Django threadedcomments in a modal dialog and getting KeyError

Tags: django

I'm getting a `KeyError (Exception Value: 'request)` when using a modal dialog and using Ajax.
Here's my setup:

When someone clicks on a link, there is an ajax call that runs a function to query an object called part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".lib", function () {
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
         $.get("/models/"+id+"/viewmodelinfo/", function(data) {
           $(".modal-body").html(data);
           $('#mySymModal').modal('show');
       });
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is the function which queries the part object:

```
def viewmodelinfo(request, model_id):
  part = Part.objects.get(id=model_id)
  return render_to_response("models/viewmodelmodal.html", {"part": part })
```

This sends back html data which is replaced in the `modal-body` div of my modal dialog.

This all works fine, EXCEPT when I have the following line of code in the `viewmodelmodal` template:

```
{% comments part %}
```

In this case I'm getting a `KeyError`.

Here's the traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/store/models/views.py" in viewmodelinfo
  467.   return render_to_response("models/viewmodelmodal.html", {"part": part })
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  171.         return t.render(Context(dictionary))
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  62.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1178.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/store/apps/threadedcomments_extras/templatetags/comments_tag.py" in comments
  13.         "request": context["request"],
File "/Users/user1/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __getitem__
  54.         raise KeyError(key)

Exception Type: KeyError at /models/384/viewmodelinfo/
Exception Value: 'request'
```

This comment works fine everywhere else that I use it. Which leads me to think I should be including something that I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the `comments` in `{% comments part %}` ? and are you using `django-mptt` for threaded comments?

Comment: I'm using threadedcomments... I think they're related. ..http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/

Comment: use `django-mptt`. It is better for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly , you want to reload your div with new data coming from server. Without page refresh. I had the almost same issue. If you are using `django-mptt`, reloading a `mptt tag` is a little bit tricky.

I dont know about your model and view architecture, but one of the ways that helps you on this is keeping the `html` which has mptt tag ( like `recursetree` or other ones ) in another single html file. And load it into your div via `jQuery's` `load` function when ajax or post function executed.

```
$('#pre_comments').load('comments_div.html #comments');
```

This code loads all the div which has id `comments` in `comments_div.html`,  into `pre_comments` div in your current page.

So use comments_div.html page for saving and reading in your view. You can load its content into yor modal.

I am sorry if i get wrong this question.

**Note**: If more code or explanation needed, feel free to say it.

**UPDATE:**

Can you update your view like this?. Then check you $.get request again with `data.part`.

```
def viewmodelinfo(request, model_id):
    from django.core import serializers
    part = Part.objects.get(id=model_id)
    if part:
        json = {part,}
        data = serializers.serialize('json',json)
        return HttpResponse(data)       

    return render_to_response("models/viewmodelmodal.html", {"part": part })
```

Comment: Thanks -- so the `{% comments part %}` is already in another HTML file which is loaded when the user clicks on the link. So I think I have it setup as you described more or less... I think... Except instead of loading one tab only, I load the whole div which contains several tabs -- one of which is the comments.

Comment: Yes. you can specify which div excatly you want to load in to a specific div in your html file. Better if you use django-mptt. but i think threadedcomments has likely same way. Use that single html file to keep comments. always write there and read there. when you need to write new data, write that file and load it into your modal. thats it.

Comment: That's what I'm doing but still getting this key error. Is there maybe a tag or something I'm not loading properly relating to `request`?

Comment: I'll try django-mptt if I really need to, but would like to figure out this since it's working everywhere else fine!

Comment: Your views looks like correct. Do you get this error in XHR logs? while executing $.get? or classic 404 page? and one more thing , try `data.part` instead of `data`.  Because you have value in your view for part variable.

Comment: I see the error when I go to the HTML template directly that is used to replace the information in `modal-body` but the way I found it was from the XHR logs. Yes, the `part` is fine, which is why it's a strange error!

Comment: yes. actually better if you send that query as `JSON`. I am not sure you can reach correctly under jquery with that way.

Comment: How would I send it as JSON? Sorry I'm a noob. I'll try that if it's not too difficult.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28278/discussion-between-drterminal-and-user1328021)

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a LOT of searching I found the answer, which is relating to accessing request in django custom template tags....

You can see the answer here: [Access request in django custom template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160261/access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags)

I used the following:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
```

and then changed the following line:

```
  return render_to_response("models/viewmodelmodal.html", {"part": part }),
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I really hope this helps someone else! :-)