# using request.user in templatetags in Django

Tags: django, django-template-filters, templatetags, django-2.0

I am using `Django 2.0`

I have three tables `notes`, `starred` and `shared`

notes model

```
def Notes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

def Starred(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def Shared(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the note can be shared with multiple users and multiple users can star the note which will be listed in their `/starred` notes

views.py has

```
class SharedNotes(ListView):
    template_name = 'notes/shared.html'
    model = Shared
    context_object_name = 'shared_notes'

    def get_queryset(self):
        shared_notes = Shared.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return shared_notes

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(self.__class__, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I have written a separate template snippets to display list of notes and add `*` (star) if it is starred by logged in user using

```
{% if note.starred_set.all %}
<span class="card-star">
    <i class="material-icons">star</i>
</span>
{% endif %}
```

But this way star is showing with other users the note has been shared with even when they have not starred the note but has been starred by someone else.

**How to filter the starred only to logged in user?**

I thought of to write a tag to be used like

```
{% if note.pk|starred %}
<!-- add html star code here -->
{% endif %}
```

and filter tag in `templatetags/my_tag.py`

```
@register.filter(name='starred')
def starred(value):
    note = Note.objects.get(pk=value)
    if note is not None:
        starred_note = Starred.objects.filter(note=note, user=value['request'].user)
        if starred_note is not None:
            return True

    return True
```

But this gives error as

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: it is `int` as I'm using `note.pk`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access request in django custom template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160261/access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags)

Comment: @kichik it is now giving error as `starred requires 2 arguments, 1 provided`. My tag now looks like `@register.filter(name='starred', takes_context=True)
def starred(value, context):`