# Where to import stuff for a template in Django?

Tags: django

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm lost.

I got a template and a templatetags with this :

**menu_tags.py**

```
from django import template
from menu.models import Button

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('menu/home.html')
def show_menu():
    buttons = Button.objects.all()
    return {'buttons': buttons}
```

And this :

**home.html**

```
    {% for button in buttons %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      stuff
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I would like to know, how can I make user.is_authenticated work ? I know I have to import something, but where ? Importing it in menu_tags does not seems to work.

Thanks !

Comment: Or you can use `request.user.is_authenticated`

Comment: Always return false for me.

Comment: Is user is authenticated ? By what method ?

Comment: Well with the basic Django system... I can use the "user.is_authenticated" in my base template but not in my menu app if that help you...

Comment: `request` is not available in template tags. You have to get it first. Check out the answers here: [Access request in django custom template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160261/access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags). Then use `request.user.is_authenticatated`.

Comment: Yes I actually just corrected this. Now I can use it in my template tags but not in my template (home.html) :(

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users in the comments, try the following:

```
from django import template
from menu.models import Button

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('menu/home.html', takes_context=True)
def show_menu():
    request = context['request']
    if request.user.is_authenticated: # if Django 1.10+
        buttons = Button.objects.all()
    else:
        buttons = None
    return {'buttons': buttons}
```

And then in your template, make sure you load your new templatetags and try:

```
{% load menu_tags %}

{% for button in buttons %}
  {{ button }}
{% endfor %}
```